# PostgreSQL: require explicit time zone on INSERT/UPDATE of timestamptz columns

Tags: postgresql

I'm digging into how Postgres works and have decided that any date/time data in my database should be of datatype timestamptz.

The rules that govern how Postgres parses date/time information vary based on the server's timezone, the client session timezone, and/or the database timezone setting. I can't expect my developers to know all of this, so to avoid any ambiguity I would like to somehow procedurally require a timezone be specified in any INSERT or UPDATE to a timestamptz column, and for any UPDATES or INSERTS to fail when the input value for a timestamptz column doesn't explicity include a time zone. I've created a regex that I can use to match against the input value; I just don't know how to hook up the plumbing.

I first thought I could do this with a custom domain; however, it appears that the CHECK constraint on a domain is done *after* the input string has already been parsed, so that won't work. (By then, the server has already inferred the time zone for values where time zone wasn't explicitly included.)

I could use a custom data type, but that's a whole can of worms there and I'm not sure that doing so would preserve all of the operators and functions that would operate on the underlying timstamptz column.

I could use BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers, but doing so would require me to iterate over every column in the NEW record, determine its datatype, then check the value against a regex to ensure a time zone is specified.

Does the community have any ideas on how to accomplish this? I think the BEFORE INSERT/BEFORE UPDATE is likely the best place to do this work, but I don't know how to iterate over the new record and find the data type for each column.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't expect my developers to know all of this

I think that's your problem. If you want to use PostgreSQL and work with time zones, you need your developers to understand it.

It's all very simple: Only set the `timezone` parameter correctly for the client session, then everything will just work.